# Error de lógica (casos no contemplados)

Tags: algoritmos, condiciones, c++11, else, lógica

que tal? Tengo un problema, estoy aprendiendo a programar y estoy resolviendo este problema en Omegaup: [Enlaces](https://omegaup.com/arena/problem/duracion_de_juego#problems)

Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int inicial, final, total;

   std::cin >> inicial >> final;

   if (inicial == final)
       std::cout << "24" ;

   else if (inicial < final and final > 12)
       std::cout << abs(final - inicial);

   else if (inicial > final and inicial > 12)
   {
       total = abs(inicial - final);

       std::cout << abs(total - 24);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Alguna sugerencia de algún caso que no este contemplando?

Comment: Hola, estás teniendo un error o estas consultando si te falta contemplar algo? Hay casos en los que no esta bueno poner muchos if anidados, y para eso existe switch. Se configura un comportamiento para cada condicion que tengas, y se configura un comportamiento por defecto si la condicion es distinta a todas las opciones anteriores. Te dejo un link con mas info https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha sido útil, acuérdate de votarla, no solo aceptarla! Gracias y ánimo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te has dejado 2 casos esenciales:

1. En tu primer `else if` tienes en cuenta qué pasa cuando `inicial < final`pero no si `final<12`.
2. Lo mismo para el segundo `else if`

Te ha faltado debuggear bastante con tu programa y darle vueltas. Te recomiendo que en una libreta te dibujes tus números y cosillas, y vayas debuggeando con el IDE que utilices o por consola! No tengas miedo de hacer prints!

Hay maneras más óptimas de hacerlo pero me he ceñido a corregir cómo lo tenías tu! Que así seguro que lo entiendes mejor!

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int inicial, final, total;

   std::cin >> inicial >> final;

   if (inicial == final)
       std::cout << "24" ;

   else if (inicial < final and final >= 12)
       std::cout << abs(final - inicial);
    else if(inicial < final and final<12)
        std::cout<<(final-inicial);

   else if (inicial > final and inicial > 12)
   {
       total = abs(inicial - final);

       std::cout << abs(total - 24);
   }
   else
    std::cout<<(24-inicial+final);

   return 0;
}
```

Y esto ya es una manía mía! Si pones antes del `main`, (debajo de los `#include`), `using namespace std;`, te olvidas de tener que poner `std::cout` siempre, pudiendo poner `cout`directamente!